# Convert JSONP response string to JSON in node

Tags: json, node.js, string, jsonp

Im making a request on a node server to an endpoint that is returning JSONP. I tried removing the callback param and the request fails. Looking for a way to convert this JSONP response into normal JSON.

```
{ data: 'callback1241232([201, {"name": "Thomas"}]);'}
```

Expected

```
{ data: [201, {"name": "Thomas"}] }
```

`axios` is the library that I'm using to make these requests and it doesn't convert this for you.

Comment: give it a callback to use, then strip it out of the string.

Comment: All I have is this object that you see above, what callback is there to use?

Comment: *"Im making a request on a node server to an endpoint that is returning JSONP. I tried removing the callback param and the request fails."* that's the callback i'm referring to.

Comment: The endpoint takes a callback param, this param is used to wrap the function, this is for client-side use so when the script loads on the page the callback fires. I can't do anything with this on the server...

Comment: right, so give it a callback param, and then on the server remove the callback from the JSONP string. this is very simple string manipulation, you don't even need regexp.

Comment: my request is `axios.get('http://ex.com/jsonp-res?callback=callback1241232')` and I get back this data object above from the promise, there's nowhere to put a callback.

Comment: @KevinB are you suggesting regex?

Comment: Regex can do the job, but you don't need it since you know the length and position of the string you want to remove.

Comment: I'm not at a pc so I can't give any examples

Comment: Does the API offer any support for requests without the callback or *padding* in the response? Typically, JSONP is implemented as an option with JSON APIs rather than a requirement. And, Node isn't bound by an origin, so JSONP's purpose is sort of lost on it.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I hear you, unfortunately not I'm specifically trying to access a JSONP exclusive api.

Comment: @KevinB what's a pc?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it using `regex`.

```
return axios.get('http://ex.com/jsonp-res?callback=callback')
.then(data => {
  data = JSON.parse(data.data.replace(/^callback\(|\)\;/g, ''))
  console.log(data)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using the dreaded `eval`.

```
return axios.get('http://ex.com/jsonp-res?callback=callback')
.then(data => {
  function callback(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
  eval(data.data)
})
```